# Server not responding using Curl POST Request

Tags: php, curl

I am using this code to get the contents of a `post` request url using `php curl`

Code looks as below:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www1.ptt.gov.tr/tr/interaktif/sonuc-yd.php',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'barcode' => 'CP021325078TR',
    'security_code' => $capcha2
)
));

 // Send the request & save response to $resp
 $resp = curl_exec($curl);
 // Close request to clear up some resources
 curl_close($curl);

 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($resp);
 echo "</pre>";
```

The result doesn’t seem to return anything at all.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www1.ptt.gov.tr/tr/interaktif/sonuc-yd.php';
$postvals = array(
    'barcode' => 'CP021325078TR',
    'security_code' => $capcha2
);
$resp = Request($url,$postvals);
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($resp); exit;
```

...

```
function Request($url,$params=array()){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlOpts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true
            );
        if(!empty($params)){
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
        }
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOpts);
        $answer = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            echo curl_error($ch); exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $answer;
    }
```

EDIT:

I tested this and got:

```
Could not resolve host: www1.ptt.gov.tr
```

So make sure you're calling the right endpoint.

Comment: from where did u test that?

also here u have the link where u can manually make a request and see what happens in background:
http://www1.ptt.gov.tr/tr/interaktif/kayitliposta-yd_yeniweb.php

Comment: that page isn't loading in my browser either.

Comment: @LulzimFazlija it means the DNS cannot find an actual IP address for that domain.

Comment: it means that site doesn't exist.

Comment: ok i found out smth , this site uses session, so each time u call that site generates a session id, that means i have to get that session id to the request somehow

Answer (score -1):

Actually you need to set this variable

```
 $captcha2
```

To use it here -

```
'security_code' => $capcha2
```